# How to check if a .webp file is a gif or image in python using PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, image, png, webp

I was trying to make a ".webp extractor script" in python where I'd loop through a pre-determined file directory searching for .webp's to then decide whether they were a .gif file type saved as a .webp or not so I could save the .webp as a  .gif or if it wasn't a .gif as a .webp it would therefore be a image such as a .jpg/.png saved as a .webp so I could just save the .webp as a image.

However, detecting whether a .webp was storing a gif or image was a bit confusing, here was my code prior to checking :

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

for entry in os.scandir(Directory):
    Searched += 1
    if entry.path.endswith(".webp") and entry.is_file():
        print("--------------")
        print("Found a : .webp")
        print(entry.path)

        IsAGif = False

        MediaFile = Image.open(entry.path)
```

Then I was stuck from there and had to try find some solutions. But I had to change my mindset and think, logically. And what I thought was that .gif have multiple image frames whereas a image such as a .png only has one. So if I could read the .webp file and find that out, I could distinguish between a image and .gif...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And eventually, I found how to read the frames in a image / .gif which was :

```py
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

MediaFile = Image.open(entry.path)
for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(MediaFile):
     #Rest of code here
```

Hence, to find if a .webp is a .gif or image, I just need to read how many frames there are. If there is one frame, the .webp is a image, else if it is more than one frame it is a .gif because it's transitioning between the frames. Hence I present a function for this :

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def IsAGif(FilePath):
    try:
        MediaFile = Image.open(FilePath)
        Index = 0
        for Frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(MediaFile):
            Index += 1
        if Index > 1: #Must mean the the .webp is a gif because it has more than one frame
            return True
        else: #Must mean that the .webp has 1 frame which makes it a image
            return False
    except: #If the .webp can't be opened then it is most likely not a .gif or .webp
        return False
```

Comment: you can skip if...else... with `return index > 1` right after `Index += 1` to make the code shorter.